# How to cover 100% branches of this piece of code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Here is the function in question (the switch statement is where coverage is not right)

[image]

Here is the coverage statistics in question
[image]

I have this switch case whose branches I seem to have covered. The coverage bubble says this block was hit 6 times

My tests test the following

- 4 times for ADD/MODIFIED
- 1 time each for the other cases. But, the bubble says that all the cases were invoked with '0' .

Question ?

- What does the "0" represent in the coverage stats bubble ? Is it the ENUM ordinal value with which this switch was invoked ? If yes, then why isn't it showing other values since I covered them too ?

Comment: You have to read the messages.  The first message says "ConfigMap { } is modified and no notification is sent to its corresponding component."

Comment: Sorry, I dont follow.

Comment: The bottom picture you posted has some messages.  Read them.

Comment: I did and as I said my test are passing in every possible enum value. So that means the 0 I thought to be the enum ordinal is actually the hits for those cases ???? Which means, the cases aren't being hit at all ?